# audio resampler DSP rounding duration instead of truncating

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm using the audio resampler DSP (CLSID_CResamplerMediaObject) as an MFT (IMFTransform) under Windows 7.  The program is in C++ developed with Visual Studio Community 2015.  I'm changing the number of channels from 2 to 1 and the sampling rate from 48 to 44.1KHz.  Occasionally a returned media sample will have had its duration rounded up to the nearest hns instead of truncated toward zero (per Microsoft's own recommendations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/dd940438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are rounded durations to be expected from the resampler?

Comment: You should perhaps have some sample data included, where time stamps are not as you expect them.